# Is there a way to disable react-oauth/google auto login?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, react-oauth

I'm using @react-oauth/google library to authenticate the user, but I don't really want to save all that information on the cookies. I know that the  component has an auto_select prop that I can pass false to, but in this case I'm using the useGoogleLogin hook in a custom button.

```
` const googleSignup = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: async (tokenResponse) => {
      // signupGoogle({ tokenId: tokenResponse.access_token })
    },
  })
`
```

and then I use it in my button

```
`<ButtonComponent
    width="100%"
    label="Continue com o Google"
    variant="white-lined"
    icon={<GoogleIcon />}
    styles={{ gap: '1rem' }}
    onClick={() => { googleSignup() }}
 /> `
```